# Chose which tasks to do to earn the biggest amount of money possible

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I can't get my head around this problem:

- You're given **n** tasks
- Each task has time **t**, which represents the **time** needed to finish the task(**t[i]** is the time needed for **i**-th task)
- **r[i]** represents **deadline** for the **i**-th task (we start at time=0, and **r[i]** is an int that represent when the task must be finished)
- if the task is done before deadline, you get a **reward** which is **p[i]** for the task **i**
- You need to calculate the **maximum reward** you can get by doing a combination of theese tasks
- A reward is given only if a **deadline** is met
- All values are **integers**
- The solution must be of the **lowest complexity** possible

I tried to apply greedy method, but I realized that algorithm wouldn't always give the ooptimal solution. I can write a brute force algorithm, but that's not the point. I think that dynamic programming maybe can be used, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3):

If all the times are equal, then the system can be shown to be a matroid and the greedy algorithm will give optimal results (see chapter 16 of "Introduction To Algorithms" by Charles E. Leiserson, Thomas H. Cormen, Clifford Stein, and Ronald Rivest).

However, suppose times are not equal, in general in this case the problem is NP-hard.

To see why, consider the case when all the deadlines are a fixed value.  Then the problem is equivalent to finding the best way of packing items into a fixed time budget and is equivalent to the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) which is known to be NP-complete.

In your particular case, the times are integers so you may be able to adapt the [dynamic programming approach for Knapsack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming_in_advance_algorithm).

I would recommend attempting to solve this using dynamic programming based on the subproblem f(t) which is the smallest penalty for scheduling all tasks with deadlines less than or equal to t.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. It helped. I actually solved it by using modified dynamic programming approach for Knapsack.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using dynamic programming. **f[i]** is the maximum reward you can get by the **i**-th hour. The solution is **f[max(r)]**, where **max(r)** is the largest value from the deadlines.

In my solution, you also need a list **X[i]**, where X[i] represents the optimal list of tasks you should do by the **i**-th hour to get the biggest award.

Here's pseudocode:

```
LIST x0...n = empty;  // x0, x1....xn are all different lists
f[0] = 0;
for i=1 to max(r) do
    max = f[i-1];
    x[i] = x[i-1];
    for j=1 to n do
        if t[j] <= i and r[j] >= i and j.isNotElementOf(x[f[i-t[j]]]) then
            reward = p[j] + f[i-t[j]];
            if reward > max then
                max = reward;;
                x[i] = x[i-t[j]];
                x[i].add(j);
    f[i] = max;
return f[max(r)];
```